# Jekyll filter plug-in error "undefined method `-@' for :liquify:Symbol"

Tags: ruby, plugins, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to use a Jekyll plug-in that expands nested liquid variables in the YAML front matter, but am receiving the following console error after attempting to run the site locally:

```
$ jekyll serve -w
Configuration file: /Users/consortia/Documents/consortia2017-v4/_config.yml
Configuration file: /Users/consortia/Documents/consortia2017-v4/_config.yml
jekyll 3.4.0 | Error:  undefined method `-@' for :liquify:Symbol
```

The code for my plug-in file (liquify_filter.rb) is as follows:

```
---
---

module Jekyll
  module LiquifyFilter
    def liquify(input)
      output = Liquid::Template.parse(input)
      output.render(@context)
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::LiquifyFilter)
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the full error message with the stack trace and the line number in which the error occured.

Comment: @spickermann I edited my original post to show all of my terminal commands prior to the error. Unfortunately, it does not include a line number for the error. I may be confused about how to do a proper stack trace, so forgive my ignorance!